# Parse JSON number array using Gson

Tags: java, json, gson

This is the JSON string I want to parse with Gson. I would like to quick and simple to parse it.

```
{
    "values": [
        [
            1, 
            1, 
            0, 
            0, 
            0, 
            0, 
            11, 
            0.09090909090909091
        ], 
        [
            [
                0, 
                0, 
                0, 
                0, 
                0, 
                1, 
                0
            ], 
            [
                0, 
                0, 
                0, 
                0, 
                0, 
                1, 
                0
            ], 
            [
                0, 
                0, 
                0, 
                0, 
                0, 
                0, 
                0
            ], 
            [
                0, 
                0, 
                0, 
                0, 
                0, 
                0, 
                0
            ], 
            [
                0, 
                0, 
                0, 
                0, 
                0, 
                0, 
                0
            ], 
            [
                0, 
                0, 
                0, 
                0, 
                0, 
                0, 
                0
            ], 
            [
                0, 
                0, 
                0, 
                0, 
                0, 
                11, 
                0
            ], 
            [
                0, 
                0, 
                0, 
                0, 
                0, 
                0.09090909090909091, 
                0
            ]
        ]
    ]
}
```

but I don't know how to write the parsing code with Gson. 
Best result is if I can extract List from the parsed object.

Is any possible that i Write a class like that.

```
class Value  
{  
    @SerializedName("0")   
    List<Float> value1;   
    @SerializedName("1")   
    List<Integer> value2;   
    ...........   
 }
```

Thanks for everyone to help me.

Comment: Good to know that you wantto parse, but what data do you want to fetch?

Comment: And also, what have you tried so far ?

Comment: I want to get all infomation parse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the fastest way I know to get the info you need in the most usable format for you.

Your JSON is made of a list that contains list1 - a list of double - and list2, a list of list of double. Assuming that you want to parse exactly the example you provided with, this is a self contained class that you can use.

If you need mode details on how it works, feel free to ask.

```
package stackoverflow.questions;

import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.List;

import stackoverflow.questions.Test.Wrapper;

import com.google.gson.*;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;

public class Q20118749 {

   /**
    * @param args
    */
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      String json = "{\"values\":[[1,1,0,0,0,0,11,0.09090909090909091],[[0,0,0,0,0,1,0],[0,0,0,0,0,1,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,11,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0.09090909090909091,0]]]}";

      JsonElement je = new JsonParser().parse(json);
      JsonArray list = je.getAsJsonObject().get("values").getAsJsonArray(); // to get rid of the value part

      Type listType1 = new TypeToken<List<Double>>() {}.getType();
      Type listType2 = new TypeToken<List<List<Double>>>() {}.getType();

      Gson g = new Gson();

      List<Double> listOfDouble = g.fromJson(list.get(0), listType1);
      List<List<Double>> listOfListOfDouble = g.fromJson(list.get(1), listType2);

      System.out.println(listOfDouble);
      System.out.println(listOfListOfDouble);
   }

}
```

This is my execution:

```
[1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 11.0, 0.09090909090909091]
[[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 11.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.09090909090909091, 0.0]]
```

If your data changes, of course, you have to change this code according.

Comment: I update my question,Thanks for answer me.But I really want to write a class using the class.Thanks

Comment: What exactly does not satisfy you?

Answer (score 0):

Use this code.

```
public class MyObject{
  @SerializedName("values")
  private Values[] mValues;

  public Value[] getLoc() {
return mvalues;
}
}

public class Values{
 @SerializedName("0")
 private Zero[] mZero;

 @SerializedName("1")
 private One[] mOne;

 public Zero[] getZero() {
return mZero;
 }

 public Value[] getOne() {
return mOne;
 }
}

public class Zero{
 @SerializedName("0")
 private zint zero;

 public  int getZeroValue() {
    return zero;
 .........
 }

}
```

like this you have to write